# Evaluate xpath expression using local-name() function when xml has namespaces and multiple tags

Tags: xml, xpath, namespaces, xml-namespaces

I have to extract the text 'testpoc' from the xml below. 
Kindly help me by providing the relevant xpath for the same.

```
               '<am:entry>`    `    
  `                <am:content type="application/xml">`
                    `<s:series-poc>`
                       '<s:c_series.c_id>testpoc</s:c_series.c_id>'   
                     </s:series-poc>                    
                   </am:content>
                </am:entry>
```

I have tried using the following paths but no luck.

a)("//*[local-name()='c_series.c_id']/text()"),

b)("/entry/content/series-poc/c_series.c_id/text()"),

c)("/entry/content/series-poc//*[local-name()='c_series.c_id']/text()")

Thanks for all your support in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

Your XPath API should provide some way of binding a namespace prefix to a URI, for example

```
XPath.declareNamespace("am", "http://something.com/");
XPath.declareNamespace("s", "http://something.else.com/");
```

You can then select the content as

```
/am:entry/am:content/s:c_series.c_id
```

Predicates relying on `local-name()` are a last resort if you aren't able to bind prefixes in this way.

What API are you using?

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for your quick response. I have posted my namespaces and entire xml. I have also posted the code that i am trying to formulate my xpath, however, no luck in extracting the respective text.

Answer (score 0):

Providing you the details, also check the xml below -

Namespaces used : 
 
    xmlns:c="http://iddn.abc.com/ns/core" xmlns:f="http://iddn.abc.com/ns/fields" xmlns:a="http://iddn.abc.com/ns/assets" xmlns:s="http://iddn.abc.com/ns/search">

```
     <atom:entry>
        <atom:content type="application/vnd">
          <s:series-item-abc-poc>
            <s:c_series.c_id>testpoc</s:c_series.c_id>
          </s:series-item-abc-poc>
         </atom:content>
     </atom:entry>
```

I tried declaring the namespaces as you suggested, however, i was unable to fetch the value for s:c_series.c_id tag. This is what i did -

xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

XPath.declareNamespace("s", "http://iddn.abc.com/ns/search");

expr = xpath.compile("//atom:entry/atom:content/s:series-item-abc-poc/s:c_series.c_id/text()");

Let me know in case i am missing on something here.

Thanks for your support on this one.

Comment: Note, this answer provides a solution for the case where the XPath expression is run from a Java application using the JAXP API. There's nothing in the question to suggest that this is the programming language or API that the OP is using. I asked the OP for details of the API but it seems they didn't understand the question.

Comment: Please ignore previous comment: I misread it your "answer" not realising it was actually an addition to the question. This "answer" should have been an edit to the original question. It suggests that the API you are using is the Java JAXP API. You are using the right approach, but of course you need to declare the "atom" namespace as well as the "s" namespace. If your attempt to solve the problem fails, please be more specific about exactly how it fails.